# Use letter keys to input number without Fn function

Tags: debian, keyboard

My keyboard does not have a Fn key, nor a number pad. But I would like to input lots of number with a number pad layout. I wonder if there is an application, which can change some letters, say, `890-iop-kl;` as a number pad when I activate the option.

I use Debian Jessie system. It will be better if the function is realized by command-line like things so that I could extend it to what I want.

Thanks very much.

Comment: For X11, you'd likely use `xmodmap`. I know I've seen a question about that too but can't seem to find it right now. Maybe it is over on [unix.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A program would need to fetch the keyboard input and translate it, which is exactly what a **keymap** ('*keybard layout*') does: map your key strokes to characters.

I'd suggest you just **switch temporarily** to a **keymap**/keyboard layout that has a number block. I know that *[Neo2](http://www.neo-layout.org/)* has a number pad layout on layer 4, though the other layers are not even near to QUERTY. You could use any mechanism to change the key map temporarily. Desktop environments like [GNOME](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-layouts.html) or [KDE](https://superuser.com/questions/268826/how-to-configure-kde-for-convenient-switching-between-3-keyboard-layouts#322246) make this possible with keyboard shortcuts or with a tray icon/mouse.

You can of course adapt a keymap yourself for this purpose, with your favourite position of the numbers.